# AWS - upload a directory from Remote share to S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager, smbj

We know the AWS transfer manager is able to copy directories to s3. But, is it possible for us to copy from a folder on remote SMBV2 share using a Java application? and we access that share using java library of smbj https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj.

I was able to achieve single file uploads by reading from directory file by file. But want I to leverage Transfer Manager directory upload. So, is it possible to copy a Directory on remote share to s3 using Transfer Manager?

Comment: Could you clarify? Can't you just download it and upload it?

Comment: No. I want to transfer files from the remote server to S3 using a Java Application. I am able to achieve by doing single file uploads reading from directory one by one. But want to leverage Transfer Manager directory upload now to upload all contents of directory as a whole.

Comment: Do you see errors when using TransferManager’s uploadDirectory method? That method is there to do exactly what you're trying. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html#transfermanager-upload-directory

Comment: `MultipleFileUpload xfer = xfer_mgr.uploadDirectory(bucket_name,
            key_prefix, new File(dir_path), recursive);` -- This requires java.io.file File path which is not possible to get as it is mounted on share volume we use smbj to access it which returns in com.hieronomus.share.file File path.